# Orbeon Forms - Wizard View automatically focus first field

Tags: orbeon

In my form I want to use Wizard View. I noticed that, when I change section, first field of the section  is automatically focused. You can find example form here: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/a82f35efaefb46cfba52ae2bb6ba1b5eec58c21d

Is is possible to disable this functionality?

I think this properties can help: https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner/form-runner-detail-page#focusable-controls

But I am not sure how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `oxf.fr.detail.initial-focus` property that you are looking for. You can disable that "initial focus" behavior that you are describing by adding the following property to you `properties-local.xml`.

```
<property
    as="xs:boolean"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.initial-focus.*.*"
    value="false"/>
```

If you haven't worked with properties before, you might want to got through [this page from the documentation on how to set properties](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties).